# RCaller - What exactly should setRscriptExecutable() point to?

Tags: java, r, rcaller

What filepath should `setRscriptExecutable()` point to?

I've Googled it, but nothing related to what I need comes up.

Comment: I would actually really like an answer to this question...

Answer (score 1):

On `Windows` it`C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.0.2\\bin\\Rscript.exe` and on `Linux/MacOS` it is `/usr/bin/Rscript`

I think the best way to set it, is just like in the examples:

```
RCaller caller = new RCaller();
Globals.detect_current_rscript();
caller.setRscriptExecutable(Globals.Rscript_current);
```

Comment: Where are these examples?

Comment: examples: https://github.com/jbytecode/rcaller/tree/master/RCaller/src/main/java/examples

Comment: also you should use the latest version of `RCaller 2.8`: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.jbytecode/RCaller/2.8

Comment: the blog posts also have examples: http://stdioe.blogspot.com.tr/search/label/rcaller